# Is there a terminology for [CLASS_NAME]:[METHOD_NAME]:[LINE_NUMBER] for java doc comment

Tags: java, javadoc

I am creating documentation for my code where I am using StackWalker to retrieve StackFrames and get info like className,methodName,LineNumber .

In order to mention on the method details in my javadoc segment , I want to know the correct terminology for

```
[CLASS_NAME]:[METHOD_NAME]:[LINE_NUMBER]
```

Currently I am referring to it as `Location in Code` .
But this doesn't sound satisfactory .

Is there a more suiting terminology ?